# Share a post on linkedin company page

Tags: share, linkedin-j

i would like to know if we can post on LinkedIn company page instead of my wall. and if we can how can we.

right now all the share links i saw is sharing content on my wall but not on company page i create.

thank you and with best regards
Roger